# What is different between Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath.Rnd and the old VB Rnd() function?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert some old VB code to .Net but am having a problem with the Rnd function.

Old Code

```
Private Function Decode() As String

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dom Code As String = "m[n-Msr0Xn*ca8qiGeIL""7'&;,_*EV{M;[{2bEmg8u!^s*+O37!692{-Y4IS"


    x = Int(Rnd(-7))

    For r = 1 To Len(Code)

        x = Int(Rnd() * 96)
        c = Asc(Mid(Code, r, 1))
        c = c + x
        If c >= 126 Then c = c - 126 + 32

        Decode = Decode & Chr$(c)

    Next

End Function
```

The decoded text is "Bet you needed more than a pencil and paper to get this one!"

This is what I have done:

```
Private Function Decode() As String

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim Answer As String
    Dim Code As String = "m[n-Msr0Xn*ca8qiGeIL""7'&;,_*EV{M;[{2bEmg8u!^s*+O37!692{-Y4IS"


    x = CType(Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath.Rnd(-7), Integer)

    For r = 0 To sList.Length - 1

        x = CType(Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBMath.Rnd() * 96 - 0.5, Integer)
        c = Asc(sList.Substring(r, 1))
        c = c + x
        If c >= 126 Then c = c - 126 + 32

        Answer &= Chr(c)

    Next

    Return Answer 

End Function
```

but this is what I get "Bet you needed morB th(n a pencil and paper to get this one!"

I suspect its how I am castng to an int but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Why you are subtracting -0.5 in a lower sample code?

Comment: because the results are even more incorrect without it.

Comment: This is what you get without the .5 "Cfu!you nfeded npsB th)o!b!pfndjl!and qaqer!to!hft!thjt oof!"

Comment: When I run your "Old Code" under Office VBA (should be the same implementation as VB6), I get the same result as you say you get from VB.Net.

Comment: Instead of -0.5 perhaps you should use [**`Math.Floor()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor(v=vs.110).aspx)? Don't think it'll solve your problem, though - it was just a thought.

Comment: @TnTinMan Thanks, you got me to the solution.  I typed the wrong characters, I used an I (upper i) when it was an l (lower L) and used a ' when it was supposed to be a `.  If you want to post an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: If you are converting to VB .Net you should be using the Random class,

Comment: @dbsaenett that will not work.  The random class functions completely differently than the rnd function so it would be impossible to decrypt the correct values.  Unless you can provide a conversion which would require the Random class and the Rnd function to use exactly the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your "Old Code" (after correcting the typos) under Office VBA (which should have the same `Rnd` implementation as VB6), I get the same result as you say you get from VB.Net.  Therefore, there must be an error in the string assigned to `Code`.

```
Public Function Decode() As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim Code As String
    Code = "m[n-Msr0Xn*ca8qiGeIL""7'&;,_*EV{M;[{2bEmg8u!^s*+O37!692{-Y4IS"
    x = Int(Rnd(-7))
    For r = 1 To Len(Code)
        x = Int(Rnd() * 96)
        c = Asc(Mid(Code, r, 1))
        c = c + x
        If c >= 126 Then c = c - 126 + 32
        Decode = Decode & Chr$(c)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TnTinMan for leading me to the solution.  The problem was created when I copied the string.  I used a I instead of an l.  The font that was used has these two characters looking identical.  I also mistook ' for `.

so basically all I had to do was subtract .5